# How to animate UITableViewCell height?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a `UITableView` and I want it so that when you tap on the cell the height animates to a taller height (i.e: it expands). How do I do so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple actually, create an instance variable for an `NSIndexPath`, I've called it `selectedIndexPath`. Then all you need to do is make a condition in `heightForRowAtIndexPath` to  adjust the height of this specific cell independently from the rest.

Then in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` set the selected index path iVar to that of the selected cell, and call begin/end updates on the table. The cell will automatically expand with a nice animation.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath compare:selectedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return 80;
    }
    return 40;
}
```